# Module 'X' has no attribute 'Y' sometimes raised and sometimes not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiples files but two are relevant.
The first one is **PacketStrings.py** and it looks something like this:

```
import re
from scapy.all import *

def packetString(pkt):
    global attacker_ip
    global tcp_payload

    out = ""
    if (IP in pkt):
        attacker_ip = pkt[IP].src
        out += ipString(pkt[IP])
    elif (IPv6 in pkt):
        # TODO
        pass
    if (TCP in pkt):
        tcp_payload = payloadString(pkt[TCP])
        out += tcpString(pkt[TCP])
        out += "[TCP Payload]" + "\n"
        out+= payloadString(pkt[TCP])
    elif (UDP in pkt):
        out += udpString(pkt[UDP])
        out += "[UDP Payload]" + "\n"
        out += payloadString(pkt[UDP])
    return out
```

The second one is **intrusion.py** and it looks something like this

```
from PacketStrings import *
import json
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.parse
from scapy.all import *

SQLinjections = json.loads(open('/redpot/IDS/src_code/attacks/SQLinjections.json').read())

LOG = open("/redpot/logs/IDS/intrusions.log", "a")

def SQLintrusion(pkt):
    ip = PacketStrings.attacker_ip
    sus = PacketStrings.tcp_payload
    if (len(sus) != 0):
        for x in SQLinjections:
            if (conf.route.route("0.0.0.0")[2] != ip and urllib.parse.quote_plus(x) in sus):
                LOG.write(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")+" | Possible Intrusion Detected | Type = SQLinjection | IP = "+ip+" | Payload = "+str(x)+"\r\r\n")
```

When I run the function inside the second file sometimes it works without error and other times it raises the error :

AttributeError: module `'PacketStrings'` has no attribute `'attacker_ip'`

Comment: You have apparently not yet called `packetString()` with a parameter value that results in that variable being assigned a value.

Comment: @jasonharper Oh that makes a lot of sense, thanks. I'll declare the two variables as empty in the beginning and hope that solves it.